# Cannot load files in Magento altough they exist on the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, e-commerce

I have an issue with a Magento 1.5.1 installation. It's not a fresh install, but one that has been moved on another server (copied the files and the database).

It fails to load my Javascript files, so my menus and everything JS related doesn't work. This behaviour is the same in the admin as it is in the frontend store. I have tripple checked that the files are on the server and they are, I can access and edit them by FTP but not by HTTP (browser). The permission is 644 for the files and 766 for the folder that contains them.

Any clues as to why it has this behaviour? It's driving me crazy and I'm already running late on porting the website.

Comment: is the .htaccess file the same as before?  Try putting inside it setenv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "true" and see if more is revealed upon page load;  Also, I think that folders might need to be 755 or 775 -- but I could be wrong -- it's just that all of the permissions related docs that I have seen say that (and 644 for files as you have done)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your permissions are as you describe, then your web server (apache?) is behaving as expected.

A user needs execute permissions on a folder to `cd` to that folder.  When "you" change permissions to `766`, you end up with a bitmask like this

```
drwxrw-rw-
```

Or split out to be useful

```
  User  Group   Everyone
d rwx   rw-     rw-
```

So your user has **r**ead, **w**rite, and e**x**ecute permission on the folder, but the Group and Everyone permissions are only **r**ead, **w**rite.  This means the user apache is running as doesn't have execute permission, and therefore can't change to the folder, and therefore won't serve any files from that folder.

Traditionally it's `chmod 755` that you want for folders on a web-server, or **maybe** `777` if your security tolerance is such that you're comfortable with any user account on the system have write access to that folder.  If you can't make that judgment call you may want to consider finding a specilized host with IT/Magento support services, as hosting a web application (even a "simple" ecommerce store) is a daunting task on 2012's internet.

Comment: Thanks alot, this was indeed the issue. Works like a charm now.

Comment: Magento normally needs 775 while cache and session directories are 777. `$ find -type d -perm 777
./var/session
./var/cache`

Answer (score 1):

766 is wrong, set to 775. When a directory is set to 6, it cannot be "executed" which means it cannot be accessed.